# calculate the difference of the time between In and out

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table name checkinout in which all the record of employee punch is recorded.

look like:

```
  EMP_id        time         in/out
  --------  ---------------  -------
  11        8/19/2013 08:19    I    
  11        8/19/2013 12:37    O    
  11        8/19/2013 13:29    I    
  11        8/19/2013 14:19    O    
  11        8/19/2013 16:48    I    
  11        8/19/2013 18:44    O
```

I want to calculate the difference in time of each I and O (one by one)

eg: First I =08:19

First O=:12:37

so 08:19-12:37=difference in time

so on for second and third.

Comment: what DBMS specifically is this for? SQL Server, MySql, Oracle etc

Comment: is it true that there is always an O following an I ?

Comment: as soon as we know which dbms, i could probably provide a method using cursor. alternatively it might be better for the application to do this type of aggregation. if you only had one check in and out a day you could have a solution now.

Comment: No, sometimes employee may punch as login more than 2 times means no. of I may be more in this i have to remove the other I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 then use the LAG function like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       DATEDIFF(HH, TIME, LAG(TIME) 
                            OVER ( 
                              ORDER BY TIME)) 
FROM   TABLE1
```

A working example for this can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b9d1/4)

---

If you are using SQL Server 2008 then you'll have to do an self join like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY TIME)RN 
INTO   #TEMP1 
FROM   TABLE1 

SELECT t1.*, 
       DATEDIFF(HH, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) 
FROM   #TEMP1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN #TEMP1 t2 
              ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
```

A working example for this can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b9d1/10).

---

**EDIT**
If you want  to display the difference in a `hh:mm:ss` format try something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY TIME)RN 
INTO   #TEMP1 
FROM   TABLE1 

SELECT T.EMP_ID, 
       T.TIME, 
       T.[IN/OUT], 
       CASE WHEN DIFF/3600 <10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CAST(DIFF/3600 AS VARCHAR( 
       2)) + 
       ':' 
       + CASE WHEN DIFF%3600/60 < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CAST(DIFF%3600/60 AS 
       VARCHAR(2)) 
       + ':00' minutes 
FROM   (SELECT t1.*, 
               DATEDIFF(SECOND, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) diff 
        FROM   #TEMP1 t1 
               LEFT JOIN #TEMP1 t2 
                      ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1)T
```

And here is the third version on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b9d1/26)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick reply.. My column name is "checktype" and its data type is smalldatetime and i want the difference of each I and O ..you are right but i need more help from you plz help..

Comment: If i want to display the hh:mm:ss then what i have to do?

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer and let me know if this is what you wanted.